# AWS SCP policies - combining statements

Tags: amazon-web-services, scp

There's a limit on assigning SCP policies on Root/OUs and to save resources I'm trying to combine 2-3 policy statements together into one SCP, but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have an example of how it is done in their 'organization'?

*e.g. with terraform (but the json is the important part not the creation method)*:

```
resource "aws_organizations_policy" "Allowed_EC2_AND_ES_InstanceTypes" {
    name = "Allowed_EC2_AND_ES_InstanceTypes"
    type = "SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY" 
    description = "Policy that defines which EC2 and ES Instance Types are allowed (applied via terraform)"
    tags = {"purpose": "limit EC2-ES family types"}
    content = <<CONTENT
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement1": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": ["ec2:RunInstances"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                    "t3.*",
                    "m5.*",
                    "r5.*",
                    "c5.*",
                    "m6i.*"
                  ]
                }
            }
          }
        ],
    "Statement2": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "es:CreateDomain",
                "es:CreateElasticsearchDomain"
                ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
                ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalType": [
                    "t2.*",
                    "c4.*",
                    "m3.*",
                    "m4.*",
                    "r3.*",
                    "r4.*"
              ]
           }
        }
      }
   ] 
}
CONTENT
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think there should be **one** `"Statement" : []`. Inside this [ ],  multiple items which start from `"Sid":`  are written.

In [aws-doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_statement.html):

> The Statement element is the main element for a policy. This element
> is required. The Statement element can contain a single statement or
> an array of individual statements. Each individual statement block
> must be enclosed in curly braces { }. For multiple statements, the
> array must be enclosed in square brackets [ ].
> `"Statement": [{...},{...},{...}]`

Therefore your example shown should be like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "t3.*",
                        "m5.*",
                        "r5.*",
                        "c5.*",
                        "m6i.*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "es:CreateDomain",
                "es:CreateElasticsearchDomain"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalType": [
                        "t2.*",
                        "c4.*",
                        "m3.*",
                        "m4.*",
                        "r3.*",
                        "r4.*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've actually thought about it and tried it before but it didn't work, something I did wrong apparently, because now it did work. Thanks a lot for your answer @shimo